# how to get rows that has at least 1 association row with sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, associations

I have 'Ingredient' and 'Log' Tables like this

```
[Ingredient Table]
id 
..
...
```

```
[Log Table]
id
Ingredient_id
record_date
..
...
```

the relationship is `Log.belongsTo(Ingredeint)`

how can I find all ingredients which have at least 1 row of Log?

I mean when I searching the Ingredients, If there is no related Log on Ingredient, I don't want to include that Ingredient on my search result.

what I did now to accomplish that is

```
const ingredients = await Ingredient.findAll({
    include: {
      model: Log
    },
    group: "id",
    attributes: {
      include: [
        [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("record_date")), "order_count"]
      ]
    }
  })

const sortedIngredient = ingredients
      .filter(ingredient => ingredient.dataValues.order_count > 0)
```

But I think there would be a better way.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to do a **inner join** in your include, then you would only return ingredients that have some match in the included model.

Try to change the include to:

```
include: {
  model: Log
  required: true, // <-- Add this row
}
```

More info about require can be found in the docs: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll)

Another option that maybe could help you is to add **having** to filter on a aggregated column, like this:

```
const ingredients = await Ingredient.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Log,
  },
  group: "id",
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("record_date")), "order_count"],
    ],
  },
  having: sequelize.literal("`order_count` > 0"), // <-- Add this row
});
```

Does that help?